# Where is BackendlessCollection.getTotalObjects() defined in Backendless API

Tags: backendless

The property getTotalObjects() of the BackendlessCollection is used in this example but I am not able to find a reference to it in the [GitHub SDK](https://github.com/Backendless/Android-SDK/blob/master/src/com/backendless/BackendlessCollection.java) or on the vendor site.

```
public void handleResponse( BackendlessCollection<Restaurant> restaurants )
        {
            if( firstResponse )
            {
                System.out.println( "Total restaurants - " + 
                restaurants.getTotalObjects() );
```

https://backendless.com/feature-17-data-paging-or-how-to-efficiently-load-large-data-sets-in-a-mobile-app/

Answer (score 0):

It is defined in the AbstractBackendlessCollection class. The "getTotalObjects()" method will be removed in the future version of the SDK, it will be replaced with a separate API method that counts the number of objects for a query.